# Avoid caching failed operations

Tags: java, scala, caching, playframework-2.0

**EDIT**
Start chucking (throwing exceptions) and then there there is no "bad" data to cache. By catching exceptions, even wrapped in an Either[Why-Fail, Option[T]], I was only making more work for myself. Exceptions are (ideally) exceptional, so log, throw, and move on...

**ORIGINAL**
Caching is good, but caching failed operations is bad

```
Cache.orElse("directory.active") {
  Ok( dao.findAll(active = true) as json )
}
```

The DAO database lookup could fail (in this case an empty List is returned on database/query failure) which would result in caching bad data.

How to workaround this? We only want to run the query once and then cache for further requests. In Scala you can do lazy initiliazation, but that would make a permanent cache which is also not desirable (need to clear the cache on member directory addition/edit).

Assume this applies to any platform: basically need to perform an operation once and cache it *on successful outcome*.

Comment: I'd that's what exceptions are for - to distinguish failing from successful operations. Viewing types as sets, I consider it very bad practise to "indicate" failures by some arbitrarily chosen member of the result set, e.g., to return 0 if the function returns ints, or, as in your case, the empty list as the result of a failing database query. If you dislike exceptions you could also use an ``Option``, or an ``Either``. The latter would also enable you to store a reason, the former wouldn't. (I personally see a big difference between exceptions and ``None`` options, but that's another topic.)

Comment: @mhs you are right, I need to rethink my approach. For write operations I return Either, but for read operations I have been relying on None and empty List failure conditions, which is not accurate; there is no way to tell, for example with a None result, if an SQL Exception occurred or no record was found. This is Ok provided the read is not dependent on a write (e.g. checking if an email already exists on user signup). It seems that Either is the only viable approach when working with queries as Left will always indicate an Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the Cache implementation handy, so couldn't test this, but how about something like:

```
def getCache[A](key:String, result:()=>A)(invalidTest:A=>Boolean):Option[A] = {
  Cache.get(key).getOrElse {
    result match {
      case m:A if (!invalidTest(m)) => Cache.set(key,m);Some(m)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}

getCache("directory.active", () => dao.findAll(active = true))(_.isEmpty)
```

As you said, you could easily pimp Cache to add this, with default validity tests for the types that you're putting into the cache.

If you wanted to cache the Action result instead (and if you're always returning json, and if `as json` returns type Json -- sorry, not a Play guy), maybe:

```
def getCache[A](key:String, result:()=>A)(invalidTest:A=>Boolean):SimpleResult[Json] = {
  Cache.get(key).getOrElse {
    result match {
      case m:A if (!invalidTest(m)) => Cache.set(key,Ok(m as json));Ok(m as json)
      case x:A => Ok(x as json)
      case _ => Ok(errorjson as json)
    }
  }
}

getCache("directory.active", () => dao.findAll(active = true))(_.isEmpty)
```

Comment: +1 nice @brandon, versatile to boot, can check empty List, defined Option value, etc. Should note that we want to return the result regardless, just not cache on "failed" operation.

Comment: bah ... you'll want to make it `result:=>A`

Comment: @virtualeyes if the cache has the value already, it will always return the result.  If the cache doesn't have the value, there's nothing to return (except for None or some other kind of error indication).  You could pass in a default value as another parameter to getCache (ie, an empty list).  Or, just make the second case `case _ => _` if you really just want to return whatever the result function gives you.

Comment: arggghhh, not so nice, compiler complains on "_.isEmpty" have to do, "(x:List[_]) => x.isEmpty". Just going to stick with pimping Cache method and adding checks for empty List, None, etc. within method itself.

Comment: fixed it, this actually does work, thanks for pointing me in the "right" direction, check goes the mark

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @brandon I came up with a cake-and-eat-it-too pimping of Play's [Cache implementation](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/cache/Cache.scala#L75)

```
def orElse[A,B](key: String, expire: Int = 0)
  (canFail: => B)(failOn: B => Boolean)(body: B => A)
  (implicit m: ClassManifest[A]): A = {

  PlayCache.getAs[A](key).getOrElse {
    canFail match {
      case x if(!failOn(x)) => // all good, cache away
        val tmp = body(x); set(key, tmp, expire); tmp
      case x => body(x) // never cache a failure
    }
  }
}
```

and then use like so:

```
Cache.orElse("directory.active")(dao.findAll(active = true))(_.isEmpty) { 
  model=> Ok( directory.index(model) )
}
```

what this buys us is the ability to selectively cache operations that may fail and at the same time retain the ability to cache the html wrapper into which the canFail operation is injected. In this particular case, the findAll query returns @400 member records and generates a jQuery DataTable in the html layer (150KB generated), so caching the entire operation is desirable.